# Is an abstract base class required to implement the null object pattern safely?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I've seen two different ways to implement the null object pattern.

The [first example](http://www.oodesign.com/null-object-pattern.html) has both the concrete class and the null class inheriting from a third abstract base class.

The [second example](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceNullObject.html) shows the null object class inheriting straight from the concrete class.

While the second example has the advantage of one less class to deal with for each type of object; are there any potential pitfalls to this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concrete class will likely contain data and methods. The null object probably doesn't need any (or at least not as much) member data, and it will need to override many of the methods so that they do nothing (so won't get any benefit from inheriting the concrete implementations of these).

If the null object is itself a singleton then the overhead of it containing and overriding all this content from the concrete class might not be important (it's wasteful, but there's only one instance of this waste), and it might be simpler to implement the approach from the second example. But the first example is probably to be preferred, since it avoids creating a class that inherits a load of things it doesn't want or need.

Note that in languages that support interfaces (such as Java and C#) it's likely that the concrete type and the null type both implement the same interface but don't have any direct inheritance relationship. That's one step further on from an abstract base class.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples are similar.  While the first example deals with nullness of value object, Customer, the second example deals with nullness of object with behavior as typically found in Template or Strategy design patterns.

If you look carefully, you will realize that both examples return a reference to super class while the concrete null object returned actually safeguards the client against Null Pointer Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would end up with the first example.

Indeed, inheriting from a concrete class (second example) is the best way to risk to violate [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in general, especially with the concept of null object pattern.